# Preventing site being scraped

Tags: wordpress, web-scraping

There is a wordpress site hosted at http://www.vibrantneo.org and is currently being cloned at  http://vibrantneo.123productpages.com/ **somehow**. The very odd part is that this particular domain (http://www.123productpages.com) seems to do this to **A LOT** of content, yet there are no complaints posted around the web.

This service was not opted into. It was done without consent. I've checked Firebug and there is no mention of referencing the site's original server. Is this a malicious site? Why is there no discussion about this 'service' affecting others?

*** UPDATE ***
Turns out that this 123productpages is in fact referencing the http://www.vibrantneo.org's actual files on the host somehow. For example: changing the wp-config to invalid credentials brings down both sites.

Probably a trojan of sorts. Still confusing as to how this domain and it's practices haven't been made more public. Hopefully this post finds its way to people with the same problem while I pinpoint the point of failure.

*** UPDATE #2 ***
So it looks like it's not as malicious as I suspected. Although still very unethical. It looks like it's as simple as pulling in content and changing all references to their domain. All content is still hosted on the real server.

For example: http://blah.123productpages.com would mirror www.blah.com. Granted they would have to 'setup' that particular domain on their end it seems.

My current fix involves adding a simple snippet of js to check the psuedo encrypted domain and see if it's the proper domain and redirect if it isn't.

The following is an example of blah.com. `domain` is just the domain, blah.com separated by simple 123 (a more complex key can be produced, of course).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var u = top.location.toString();
    var domain = 'b123l123a123h123.123c123o123o123m'.toString();
    var domain_decrypted = domain.replace(/123/gi, '');

    if (u.indexOf(domain_decrypted) == -1) {
        top.location = 'http://' + domain_decrypted;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: simple snippet save my day and, nice idea, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you expose content in a publicly consumable way, it can be scraped.  You could spend time looking for traffic that looks like it came from a scraper and then block that IP, but that's a tedious game of cat and mouse.

My advice would be to accept this as a reality of putting content on the web and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can send 123productpages.com a fax forbidding them to copy your content?

Here is their contact info according to whois:

> WhoIs Check for 123productpages.com :
>
> =-=-=-=
>
> Registered through: DomainPeople, Inc.
>
> Domain name: 123productpages.com
>
> Registrant Contact:    WhoisProtector Inc.    WhoisProtector
>   123productpages.com ()
>          Fax:     100 N Riverside, Suite 800    Chicago, IL 60606    US
>
> Administrative Contact:    WhoisProtector Inc.    WhoisProtector
>   123productpages.com (123productpages.com@WhoisProtector.com)
>   +1.3129947654    Fax:     100 N Riverside, Suite 800    Chicago, IL 60606    US
>
> Technical Contact:    WhoisProtector Inc.    WhoisProtector
>   123productpages.com (123productpages.com@WhoisProtector.com)
>   +1.3129947654    Fax:     100 N Riverside, Suite 800    Chicago, IL 60606    US
>
> Status: Locked
>
> Name Servers:    ns1.publishergateway.net    ns2.publishergateway.net
>       Creation date: 28 Jun 2009 18:47:26 Expiration date: 28 Jun 2013 18:47:00

Comment: I was hoping to give somebody an earful via the WHOIS, but it looks like it's blocked via WhoisProtector.